# Haskell Data.Memocombinators performance issues?

Tags: performance, haskell, profiling, ghc, memoization

_

Hi, there,

Part of [my program to compute differences between files](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filediff) makes use of the standard DP algorithm to compute the longest common noncontiguous subsequence between two lists. I've been running into performance issues with some of this functionality, so I ran HPC to profile, and found the following result:

```
                                                individual     inherited
COST CENTRE                       no. entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
(ommitted lines above)
longestCommonSubsequence             1          0.0    0.0    99.9  100.0
 longestCommonSubsequence'           8855742   94.5   98.4    99.9  100.0
  longestCommonSubsequence''         8855742    4.2    0.8     5.4    1.6
   longestCommonSubsequence''.caseY  3707851    0.6    0.6     0.6    0.6
   longestCommonSubsequence''.caseX  3707851    0.6    0.2     0.6    0.2
(ommitted lines below)
```

Here's the offending code:

```
longestCommonSubsequence' :: forall a. (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Int -> [a]
longestCommonSubsequence' xs ys i j =
      (Memo.memo2 Memo.integral Memo.integral (longestCommonSubsequence'' xs ys)) i j

longestCommonSubsequence'' :: forall a. (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Int -> [a]
longestCommonSubsequence'' [] _ _ _ = []
longestCommonSubsequence'' _ [] _ _ = []
longestCommonSubsequence'' (x:xs) (y:ys) i j =
    if x == y
        then x : (longestCommonSubsequence' xs ys (i + 1) (j + 1)) -- WLOG
        else if (length caseX) > (length caseY)
            then caseX
            else caseY
    where
        caseX :: [a]
        caseX = longestCommonSubsequence' xs (y:ys) (i + 1) j

        caseY :: [a]
        caseY = longestCommonSubsequence' (x:xs) ys i (j + 1)
```

I find it notable that all the time and memory usage is happening in `longestCommonSubsequence'`, the memoizing wrapper. Hence, I would conclude that the performance hit is coming from all the lookups and cachings done by `Data.Memocombinators`, despite how it's always performed admirably the many other times I've used it.

I guess my question is... this conclusion seems reasonable; is it? If so, then does anyone have any recommendations for other ways to achieve the DP?

For reference, it takes 12 seconds - which is absurdly long - to compare two 14-line-long files with respective contents `"a\nb\nc\n...m"` and `"*a\nb\nc\n...m*"` (same contents but with `'*'` pre-pended and post-pended).

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: trying `ghc-core` stuff now; will post an update if I can get it to play nicely with a Cabal project and get any useful information!

Comment: The numbers you should find notable are 8855742 and 3707851, which indicate that your memoization is not working at all. madjar's answer explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Memo.memo2 Memo.integral Memo.integral (longestCommonSubsequence'' xs ys)`, it creates a memoizer for the function `longestCommonSubsequence'' xs ys`. This means that there is one memoizer for each different value of `xs` and `ys`. I guess that most of the execution time is spent creating all those data structures for all those memoizers.

Did you mean to memoize on the 4 arguments of  `longestCommonSubsequence''`?

Comment: Ah, but of course! I added the two `Int` arguments in an attempt to leverage `Memo.integral`, which should be faster than `Memo.list` -- as you see, the two `Int`s are just passed around and never used anywhere.

Hence, I would expect the following to perform better:

    `longestCommonSubsequence' i j xs ys = (Memo.memo2 Memo.integral Memo.integral longestCommonSubsequence'') i j xs ys`

since it's always memoizing the same function, and building its lookup table only based on two integers. However, I'm still seeing pretty similar profiling results. Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks! :)

Comment: Just to clarify, here; with the original implementation, it was building many tables, for one function each with one input each because the currying uniquely determines what i and j will be. In the alternative in the above comment, I would expect it to only build one table, for one function (`longestCommonSubsequence''`), with many different inputs (all values of `i` and `j`), so it seems odd that it would still be so slow.

Comment: Hmm; it seems like you can't memoize only some arguments. For someone reading this in the future with the same issue: I got around this by writing `longestCommonSubsequence'` and `''` to be 2-ary functions that take `Int`s and declared referenced `xs` and `ys` in this lower scope (note that list indexing will be slow so you might want to use Data.HashMap or Data.Vector for faster indexing)!

Comment: I was about to suggest you create your own ``Memo`` that memoize only on the list size, but I looked into it and it seems more complex than your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yeah -- this is pretty simple to code, although a bit less elegant; I guess.

Comment: Heyhey! Yeah -- good idea; here's a link: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filediff-1.0.0.5/docs/src/Filediff.html#longestCommonSubsequence